# How can I get the functionality of a command ReplaceAllList?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I'm trying to use ReplaceList to match subexpressions. I expected the command:

```
ReplaceList[{p, {p, p}}, {x_, y_} -> x y]
```

to output two results, equivalent to:
`p {p, p}`
and `{p, p p}`. That's because I expect the rule `{x_,y_}` to match both `{p,{p,p}}` and `{p,p}`. Only one result is output, equivalent to `p {p,p}`. I suppose that this is because `ReplaceAll`'s behavior of replacing all subexpressions is special, whereas the default `Replace` that `ReplaceList` must use, only matches against the first level of the rule.

That's great, but how can I get the functionality I expect? I need this to apply to arbitrary levels of nesting. For example, I would expect it to turn `{p, {p, {p, p}}}` into

```
{ p {p, {p, p}}, {p, p {p, p}}, {p, {p, p p}} }
```

(I'm trying to reproduce the work on [page 781](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-781) of the New Kind of Science book, in which subexpressions of Nand tautologies are matched/replaced according to the rules on [page 775](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-775)).

Comment: `ReplaceList[{p, {p, p}}, {{x_, y_} ->  x y, {x_, y_} :> {x, Times @@ y}}]`

Comment: @rasher yes, that works for the case I gave, but it doesn't turn `{p, {p, {p, p}}}` into `{ {p {p, {p, p}}}, {p, p {p, p}}, {p, {p, p p}} }`. Sorry for not being clear what I meant by "arbitrary levels of nesting".

Comment: NKS book has code of its examples - it's at the end:
For p.775 - [p.1155](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-1155)
For p.781 - [p.1157](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-1157) BTW whatever essential info your add in the comments - you shoudl add it to your post too.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov, p. 1157 states that "every possible transformation rule is applied wherever it can", but doesn't give an implementation. There's code on 1157, but this only generates the longest statement of its kind at every step. p. 1155 states the substitution rules I need to use, but I'm not sure how to apply one substitution rule in every possible way, at every level of the expression.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy: Ah, well, you could define transformations and use `MapAll`, or `Fold` over replacement rules. Not 100% certain `ReplaceList` alone will do what you want.

Comment: Does this work: `Function[{x}, 
 Replace[x, {z_, y_} :> HoldForm[z  y], {#}] & /@ 
  Range[0, Depth[x] - 2]]`?

Comment: This reminds me of an old question of mine on Stack Overflow: [(7944549)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7944549/618728)

Answer (score 2):

One method I've found that works, at least for this case, is to use `Position` and `MapAt`:

```
myReplaceListAll[l_, rule_] := 
 MapAt[Function[x, Replace[x, rule]], l, #] & /@ 
  Position[l, rule[[1]] ]
```

This *almost* works, except that when Position matches the whole list it returns {}, and MapAt doesn't return the whole expression.
list

```
rule = ({x_, y_} -> x y);
list = {p, {p, p}};
MapAt[f, list, #] & /@ Position[list, rule[[1]]]
```

outputs

```
{{p, f[{p, p}]}, {p, {p, p}}}
```

So in this case, to get everything to work exactly as intended, I have to write:

```
myReplaceListAll[l_, rule_] :=
  If[# != {},
     MapAt[Function[x, Replace[x, rule]], l, #],
     Replace[l, rule]
     ] & /@ Position[l, rule[[1]]];


In[]:= myReplaceListAll[{p,{p,p}},{x_,y_}->x y]
Out[]= {{p,p^2},{p^2,p^2}}

In[]:= myReplaceListAll[{p,{p,{p,p}}},{x_,y_}->x y ]
Out[]= {{p,{p,p^2}},{p,{p^2,p^2}},{p^2,{p^2,p^2}}}
```

You may also want to add the `Heads->False` option to the Position command.

Comment: You can workaround the `{}` case by wrapping `list` with some intert head, for example by `List`: `(MapAt[f, {list}, #] & /@ Position[{list}, rule[[1]]])[[All, 1]]`.